# problems wrapping my head around how to specify a index_id via a router in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set up a simplest possible backbone app that iterations through a set of images.

I want the following urls to affect the app below and have put //??? in comments where the issue is:

urls:

```
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8   -> route to startapp
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8#image/1 -> route to image with collection.at(1)
http://localhost:3000/arc/location2/8#image/2 -> route to image with collection.at(2)
```

code:

```
var imgsArray=[{'url':'/tmp-images/surf.jpg'},
    {'img':'/tmp-images/jamaica.jpg'},
    {'url':'/tmp-images/jamaica-2.jpg'}
];

arc.Image=Backbone.Model.extend({});
arc.Images=Backbone.Collection.extend({model:arc.Image});

var imgs=new arc.Images(imgsArray);
console.log(imgs.length);

var img=new arc.Image(imgsArray[0]);
```

View code and Router:

```
arc.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#mig-container'),
    initialize:function(){
      this.model=this.collection.at(0);
      this.render(this.model);
    },
    render:function(){
       var html=this.model.get('url');
       this.$el.html(html);
       return this;
   }
});
var imgView=new arc.ItemView({collection:imgs});
var HexApp = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "startapp",
        "image/:index_id": "image"
    },
    startapp:function(){
        console.log("within startapp");
        imgView.render();
    },
    image:function(index_id){
        console.log("within image: " + index_id);
        // get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'at' of undefined in Chrome
        imgView.model=this.collection.at(index_id);  //??? no idea how to manipulate this
    }
});

hex={};

var app_router = new HexApp();
Backbone.history.start();
```

How would I set the collection at the index specified by the index_id? Or is there a more idiomatic way to specify this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router can't resolve `this.collection`; that would be referring to a `collection` property within the instance of the router which you do not have defined. Instead, you would need to use the following:

```
imgView.model = imgs.at(index_id);
```

`imgs` is the variable you used early to store the instance of the collection you defined.

Comment: thx Herman, this solved this issue, Is there a better way to do this or is this ok?

Comment: I think this should be ok and I also do this myself, but I'm also still learning Backbone. You can look into a Backbone library like Marionette if you don't want to bake so much logic into the router.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have an app who's initial state renders the first image in the collection. When you hit the `image` route you want to have the `imgView` re-render using the selected image, right?

Just looking at the code it appears you've almost got it. The last thing you need to do is re-render the view after you update the model:

```
image:function(index_id){
    console.log("within image: " + index_id);
    imgView.model=this.collection.at(index_id);
    // re-render
    imgView.render();
}
```

Otherwise, I think the structure is fine for a sample app. You'll want to fix the declaration of the second item in the `imgsArray` so the key is `url` vs. `img` though. :)

Comment: thx for answer Chris; need to use something besides this.collection.

Comment: Oh, is that the problem? @HermanTran's answer should resolve that.